# Is there a way to send information TO Formstack to pre-populate a form?

Tags: formstack

So basically, I'm going to send people an email for my job. These wouldn't be cold emails, they would be for employees whose information I already have. Inside this email would be a URL, which would include some user information that would then open a Formstack form and pre-populate it. I'm guessing the easiest way to do this would be to include the user information in the URL itself, right?

As an example: John gets an email. Inside the email, there is an email that says formstack.com/survey_john_joy. John clicks the link and he goes to a survey that has John Joy pre-populated as his name.

I guess the biggest issue would be, for security issues, say I wanted to pre-populate some more sensitive information... I can't just put that in the URL. Is there a way around this? I'm guessing this would be an API call of some sort. The info would come out of a SQL database.

I think the info in the URL would work, but what about sensitive information?

Comment: https://help.formstack.com/s/article/Pre-Populating-Form-Fields

Comment: so for example like https://formstackhq.formstack.com/forms/prepopulatingformfields?name2-first=Formstack&name2-last=Support&Email2=support@formstack.com

Comment: Or if you are populating from another form:

https://formstackhq.formstack.com/forms/prepopulatingformfields?name2-first={$79264263-first}&name2-last={$79264263-last}&Email2={$79264267}